# Get data from Last Inserted Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I am trying to figure out how I would get the firstname and lastname from the INSERT statement that I just used. It created the row, and I want to use the First Name and the Last Name to use in the next insert statement, How would I go about doing this?

```
Declare @idnt int

INSERT INTO dbo.Contacts (ContactFirstName,ContactLastName,ContactCompany) VALUES ('Richard','Burns',NULL);

SELECT @idnt = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.Activity (ContactID, ActivityDate, ActivityName, ActivityNote, ActivityOwner)
VALUES (@idnt, '12/13/2011 10:55AM', 'Contact ' + @fname + " " + @lname + ", was automatically added by the system', 'Contact was automatically added by this system', 'System')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `output`!

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Activity (
    ContactID, 
    ActivityDate, 
    ActivityName, 
    ActivityNote, 
    ActivityOwner
)
SELECT 
    ContactID, 
    GETDATE(), 
    'Contact ' + ContactFirstName + ' ' + ContactLastName, 
    'Contact was added by the system.', 
    'System'
FROM (
    INSERT INTO dbo.Contacts (ContactFirstName,ContactLastName,ContactCompany) 
    OUTPUT inserted.ContactID, inserted.ContactFirstName, inserted.ContactLastName
    VALUES ('Richard','Burns',NULL)
) x
```

For more on the magic that is `output`, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

You can also use a trigger on the table to make it automagic rather than having to insert it manually each time. It uses the `inserted`/`deleted` tables, as well.

You would do that with this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Contact_LogActivity ON dbo.Contacts FOR INSERT AS
INSERT INTO dbo.Activity (
    ContactID, 
    ActivityDate, 
    ActivityName, 
    ActivityNote, 
    ActivityOwner
)
SELECT
    ContactID,
    GETDATE(), 
    'Contact ' + ContactFirstName + ' ' + ContactLastName, 
    'Contact was added by the system.', 
    'System'
FROM
    Inserted
```

Now, whenever any row gets inserted into Contacts, it logs it into Activity. For more on triggers, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: +1 I was going to mention OUTPUT... I was 10 minutes too late!

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity caught by `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, query back the table and grab the `ContactFirstName` and `ContactLastName` into your declared variables: `@fname` and `@lname` respectively:

```
...
SELECT @idnt = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT
    @fname = ContactFirstName
  , @lname = ContactLastName
FROM dbo.Contacts 
WHERE YOUR_IDENTITY_COLUMN_HERE = @idnt

INSERT INTO dbo.Activity ...
```

Replace `YOUR_IDENTITY_COLUMN_HERE` with the name of the identity column from which you assumed to grab `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from and test..

Comment: The only reason I don't like `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is that it may not be accurate--it's susceptible to a race condition where you insert a record, and another user inserts a record before your `SCOPE_IDENTITY` runs, and you get the wrong ID as a result of it. That can be *very* hard to identify as a bug when you see it happen in production.

Comment: @Eric: I don't think this would be the case - after all, it's called **scope** identity.... it will give the last inserted identity **in your scope** - so if some other user on a different connection inserts a new row - that won't affect **your** ID being returned... see [MSDN docs on SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx). `IDENT_CURRENT(tablename)` is not limited by scope - but always just returns that last ID inserted into that table specified

Comment: @marc_s: Comment redacted! I still like `output` better for readability reasons, but you're correct in that I was confusing `scope_identity`'s behavior with that of `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: @Eric: agreed - `OUTPUT` is a great if underused feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an insert with a select statement. Try this:

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.Activity (ContactID, ActivityDate, ActivityName, ActivityNote, ActivityOwner)
    SELECT @idnt, '12/13/2011 10:55AM', 'Contact ' + ContactFirstName + ' ' + ContactLastName + ', was automatically added by the system', 'Contact was automatically added by this system', 'System'
    FROM Contacts
    WHERE ContactId = @idnt
```